Lambda Function in Widget Binding Uses Last Iteration's Values
I have a loop to generate widgets dynamically, and the commands for the buttons are set using lambdas, but the event bindings for Listboxes don't seem to work well:
def fn1():

    def cbf(e, param1, param2):
        val = param2.get(param2.curselection())
        param1.delete(0, tk.END)
        param1.insert(0, val)
        
    
    def fn2():

        for x in range(n):

            entry = Entry(root, textvariable=sometextvar, bg="somecolour")
            
            lb = Listbox(root, height=someheight)
            lb.insert(0, *["Some", "values"])
            entry.bind("<FocusIn>", lambda e, entry=entry: lb.grid(row=entry.grid_info()["row"] - 1, column=2, pady=0, sticky=""))
            entry.bind("<FocusOut>", lambda e: lb.grid_remove())
            lb.bind("<<ListboxSelect>>", lambda e, param1=entry, param2=lb: cbf(e, param1=param1, param2=param2))

fn1()

I'm not sure how, but the lb.grid_remove() for <FocusOut> and the grid(...) for <FocusIn> work correctly. The one for <<ListboxSelect>> doesn't work correctly.
It works only for the last widget because, somehow, only the last widget is retained after the loop, though I'm capturing the variables when the lambda is defined (lambda e, param1=entry, param2=lb:). It also works only for the last widget for <KeyRelease>.
I've also tried functools.partial like:
lb.bind("<<ListboxSelect>>", partial(cbf, None, param1=entry, param2=lb))

both as keyword and positional arguments. I got TypeError: mainfile.<locals>.cbf() got multiple values for argument 'param1' tkinter for this one.
I've also tried around 25 other permutations and combinations of function definitions, wrapping them and nested callbacks, etc. I also don't want to use classes, and I want something like what I'm currently doing. Library functions like functools.partial are also not preferred.
Why does it work for commands of buttons and some bindings, but not for others?
Here's a MRE:
from tkinter import Tk, Entry, Listbox, StringVar
import tkinter as tk


def fn1():
    
    root = Tk()
    
    def cbf(e, param1, param2):
        val = param2.get(param2.curselection())
        param1.delete(0, tk.END)
        param1.insert(0, val)
    
    def fn2(n):
        for x in range(n):
            
            sometextvar = StringVar()
            someheight = 5
            
            entry = Entry(root, textvariable=sometextvar, bg="red")
            
            lb = Listbox(root, height=someheight)
            lb.insert(0, *["Some", "values"])
            entry.bind("<FocusIn>",
                       lambda e, entry=entry: lb.grid(row=entry.grid_info()["row"] - 1, column=2, pady=0, sticky=""))
            entry.bind("<FocusOut>", lambda e: lb.grid_remove())
            lb.bind("<<ListboxSelect>>", lambda e, param1=entry, param2=lb: cbf(e, param1=param1, param2=param2))
            
            entry.grid(row=x + 2, column=4)

    fn2(5)
    
    for r in range(root.grid_size()[1]):
        root.rowconfigure(r, weight=1)
    
    root.mainloop()

fn1()

Why is the value of the last entry set when I'm selecting the options ('Some' or 'values') from the Listbox meant for another entry? And why does the focus mechanism work?

Are you sure the two focus handlers work correctly? You should really add lb=lb to the lambda arguments, otherwise they will all reference the last list-box created in the loop.

@ekhumoro, yes, they work correctly. Even I don't understand how, but when I click the entries, the listboxes appear correctly above them, and when I click another entry, the previous listbox disappears. Please post an answer if you've figured out what's happening here.

In that case, the code in your question is completely different to your real code. Please post a proper [mre].

@ekhumoro, the code in my question is exactly the same as in my real code. Just checked. Please check the newly added MRE. It shows the same behaviour (focus mechanism works but the value is set to the last entry when selected from any listbox).

The code does not work correctly. To see it, do lb.insert(0, *[f"Some{x}", f"values{x}"]).

@ekhumoro, yes, you're right. The listbox values are also wrong, but that's not my main problem. In my code, they're the same for all listboxes, so it doesn't really matter.

You did it right for <FocusIn>, why didn't you realize you needed to do the same thing for <FocusOut>?

@Barmar, I thought the <FocusOut> worked because it just did. I didn't want to ruin that too. But I remember trying doing it for everything including <FocusOut>, but I might've made some other mistake. I didn't realize that it would lead to setting of wrong values to wrong listboxes.

So you didn't actually understand why you wrote entry=entry in the <FocusIn> binding?

@TheAmateurCoder It really does matter, because without lb=lb in the focus handlers, the select handler will reference a different list-box (except for the last one). Also, the cbf handler should check whether the current selection is empty before attempting to get the value.

When you use bind, you need to remember that tk will always send a positional parameter containing an event object. You also need to assign default values to any other arguments so that they are bound at the time the lambda is defined rather than at the time it executes.
The correct binding for <FocusOut> is this:
entry.bind("<FocusOut>", lambda e, lb=lb: lb.grid_remove())

The correct binding for <FocusIn> is this:
entry.bind("<FocusIn>", lambda e, entry=entry, lb=lb: lb.grid(row=entry.grid_info()["row"] - 1, column=2, pady=0, sticky=""))

If you are unaware, the event object contains a reference to the widget that received the event. So, in the <FocusIn> binding you can use e.widget instead of entry to cut down on the complexity of your code.

entry=entry is not necessary for <FocusIn> binding as e.widget is entry.

@acw1668: correct. I decided not to muddy the waters. I just wanted to address the issue with early/late bindings.

@BryanOakley, thanks for the answer, but in my code, the values of the listboxes are all the same. And the focus mechanism already works fine for me. Please check if you can get the <<ListboxSelect>> to work.

@TheAmateurCoder: my answer is correct. The <ListboxSelect> works with these changes. The problem was that the listbox was always the last listbox because of the broken binding to <FocusIn>.

@acw1668, wait, so e.widget is the widget? I think my problem is solved. I think I just have to use e.widget and add entry.lb = lb and then use e.widget.lb for the respective listboxes. I'll try that. Thanks a lot for your inputs.

@TheAmateurCoder: yes. The event object has a reference to the widget that received the event.

@TheAmateurCoder Note that <ListboxSelect> event will also be triggered when the listbox lost focus and exception will be raised when cbf() is executed because there is no selection in the lost focus listbox.

@acw1668, I don't get any such exception/error when I click another entry. I get it when I click on the blank area, but that's expected, right?

@TheAmateurCoder Exception will be raised if second entry is selected and click any item in the shown listbox because the selection of the last shown listbox is clear and cbf() will be executed.

@BryanOakley, you're right. Your answer works because it was the grid()ding of the wrong listboxes with the wrong values indeed.

@acw1668, I'm not really sure I understood what you're saying. I tried clicking one entry, then another. I then clicked one value in the second listbox which is shown after clicking the second entry. The second entry's value got set to the selected option as expected. I didn't get any error either. Can you please explain when the error is thrown?

@acw1668, I get the error after selecting two items. But what is the error and why does it occur? I get ...return self.tk.call(self._w, 'get', first)            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ _tkinter.TclError: bad listbox index "": must be active, anchor, end, @x,y, or a number. It says it's due to the cbf: lb.bind("<<ListboxSelect>>", lambda e, param1=entry, param2=lb: cbf(e, param1=param1, param2=param2))                                                                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^. I don't really get what's happening here.

@TheAmateurCoder: sometimes param2.curselection() returns an empty string, which you aren't guarding against. When it's empty you get an error because first is "".

@BryanOakley, when does the selection return an empty string? The error says it's not able to return self.tk.call(self._w, 'get', first). What is first? Is it the first listbox value? I don't understand when and why the selection is empty.

Can I just put all of the code in cbf in a try-except, or is the code itself wrong in some cases?

It returns an empty string when the listbox loses focus. <<ListboxSelect>> triggers when the selection changes, not only when it is set.  In the context of the error message, first is the result of param2.curselection(). You can't call get and pass it an empty string.
